# File line affecting the index of a storage array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, file, indexing, octave

I have a simple bit of code written in Octave, all is does is open 3 files (one at a time) and scans each line for one of two strings, if it finds the matching string it extracts the number which follows the string and appends that number to an array.

```
clear

names = dir('*txt');

rec = [];
emit = [];

for i = 1:length(names)
  name = names(i).name;
  fid = fopen(name);
  while !(feof(fid))
    tline = fgets(fid);
    if !(isempty(regexp(tline,'reception: ')))
      offset = regexp(tline,'reception: ');
      val = str2double(strtok(tline(offset+11:end)));
      rec(end+1) = val;
    elseif !(isempty(regexp(tline,'emission: ')))
      offset = regexp(tline,'emission: ');
      val = str2double(strtok(tline(offset+10:end)));
      emit(end+1) = val;
    end
  end
length(rec)
end

fn = strcat(name,'REC.mat');
save('-mat',fn,'rec');
fn = strcat(name,'EMIT.mat');
save('-mat',fn,'emit');
```

I expect the "length(rec) to be a cumulative value, but it's not - it just prints the number of "reception:" lines in each file, each time a new file is loaded its like the arrays "rec" and "emit" are being cleared, why does this happen? Is it to do with the file index? How can this be affecting the arrays?!

I tried this with a simple test program and it works exactly as I expect:

```
clear

test = [];
fin = 5;

for i = 1:3
  j = 0;
  while (j<fin)
    j = j+1;
    test(end+1) = j;
  end
fin = fin+5;
length(test)
end
```

length(test) prints a cumulative value (as it should). What's going on?

NOTE:

I can easily solve the problem by adding at the beginning:

```
totalRec = [];
```

and after each iteration of the for loop:

```
totalRec = [totalRec,rec]
```

But I'm interested in why it's happening.

EDIT:

An example of the content of the data files is as follows:-

```
2017.07.13 10:31:04:346301 FESA.USR.ABT_SocketServer.RealTime.CustEvtSrcProducer src/ABT_SocketServer/RealTime/CustEvtSrcProducer.cpp:168 INFO Control_data_reception: 10936 us
2017.07.13 10:31:04:363889 FESA.USR.ABT_SocketServer.RealTime.RT_NewCycleReady src/ABT_SocketServer/RealTime/RT_NewCycleReady.cpp:52 INFO RT_NewCycleReady execute -> Start
2017.07.13 10:31:05:050910 FESA.USR.ABT_SocketServer.RealTime.RT_ELFTReady src/ABT_SocketServer/RealTime/RT_ELFTReady.cpp:49 INFO RT_ELFTReady execute -> Start
2017.07.13 10:31:05:057764 FESA.USR.ABT_SocketServer.RealTime.CustEvtSrcProducer src/ABT_SocketServer/RealTime/CustEvtSrcProducer.cpp:112 INFO acquisition_data_emission: 6469 us
2017.07.13 10:31:05:474323 FESA.USR.ABT_SocketServer.RealTime.RT_endCycle src/ABT_SocketServer/RealTime/RT_endCycle.cpp:49 INFO RT_endCycle execute -> Start
2017.07.13 10:31:05:504081 FESA.USR.ABT_SocketServer.RealTime.RT_NewCycle src/ABT_SocketServer/RealTime/RT_NewCycle.cpp:59 INFO RT_NewCycle execute -> Start
2017.07.13 10:31:05:544370 FESA.USR.ABT_SocketServer.RealTime.CustEvtSrcProducer src/ABT_SocketServer/RealTime/CustEvtSrcProducer.cpp:168 INFO Control_data_reception: 9424 us
```

Comment: You code works here like described: length(rec) grows with the number of occurrences of "reception:" each file. I can't see any "magic" which influences "rec"

Comment: The test case works like described, the actual code (which reads form the file) does not. I can't see any magic either, but, for example with files which have 100, 200 and 300 occurrences of "reception:" respectively -It prints, 100, 200, 300 not 100, 300, 600...

Comment: And as I said above, I would see 100,300,600 and your first code part works. Perhaps the assumption abort a special sorting from "dir" is wrong? Nevertheless, without a good MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's difficult to help

Comment: Can you post small samples of the text files you're working with?

Comment: Yeah,. whats the best way to do that? In the question? Or add a link?